# Unexpected Response comparing Date Strings in Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to compare two date strings in my Angular Controller but I am getting unusual response.  I convert today's date to a string ("2/5/2016") and then try to compare it to string dates that I input.  Here is my code:

```
   function deleteTableRows(table) {
        var year = getToday.getFullYear();
        var month = getToday.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = getToday.getDate();
        var currentDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        var qtr4 = '12/31/' + year;
        var qtr3 = '9/30/' + year;
        for (var i = table.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (currentDate < qtr4) {
                if (table[i].intYear == year && table[i].intQuarter == 4) {
                    table.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            if (currentDate < qtr3) {
                if (table[i].intYear == year && table[i].intQuarter == 3) {
                    table.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

};
```

My issue is that when it compares currentDate('2/5/2016') to qtr4('12/31/2016') It evaluates the if statement to FALSE meaning, 2/5/2016 is NOT less than 12/31/2016.  However, it evaluates the 2nd if state to TRUE meaning, that currentDate('2/5/2016') is less than qtr3('9/30/2016').  I do not understand this behavior, but suspect that there is something simple I am missing here.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are comparing as string, convert them to date and then compare

Comment: I tried converting to date like this:         var stringDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
        currentDate = new Date(stringDate);
        var qtr4 = year + "-12-31";
        qtr4 = new Date(qtr4);
        var qtr3 = year + "-9-30";
        qtr3 = new Date(qtr3); but I get Invalid Date error for currentDate and qtr3 but NOT qtr4.  I get a date for qtr4.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should compare date using `getTime()` like: `yourDate.getTime()` and convert your string to date before use it.

```
var currentDate = new Date(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
var qtr4 = new Date('12/31/' + year);
var qtr3 = new Date('9/30/' + year);
```

and compare like

```
if( currentDate.getTime() < qtr3.getTime() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, not dates.
The slash in date is also taken into account.
String comparision compare each character from left to right. 
If the first characters are equal, then compares next characters. When next character is less, then entire string is less. 
The bug here is that '/' sign which is second is greater than '2' character, so entire string would be greater.

When you compare 2/5/2016 to 9/30/2016 it compares fine, because it takes '2' and '9' as first letter, then '/' and '/' and it works fine. 
One of the solutions here is to convert Strings to Date object and then compare them using javascript:

```
var v1 = new Date('2016-05-02')
var v2 = new Date('2016-12-31')
if ( v1 > v2 ) (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the strings to dates and then compare:

```
function deleteTableRows(table) {
    var getToday = new Date();
    var year = getToday.getFullYear();
    var month = getToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = getToday.getDate();
    var currentDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    var qtr4 = '12/31/' + year;
    var qtr3 = '9/30/' + year;
    for (var i = table.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (new Date(currentDate) < new Date(qtr4)) {
            if (table[i].intYear == year && table[i].intQuarter == 4) {
                table.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        if (new Date(currentDate) < new Date(qtr3)) {
            if (table[i].intYear == year && table[i].intQuarter == 3) {
                table.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that still is evaluating the if statement to False, meaning currentDate is NOT less than qtr4 or qtr3.

Comment: i'm not familiar with getToday but maybe make sure that, that is evaluating to today's date?  you could try setting a variable at the beginning of the function: getDate = new Date() and replace getToday with getDate?

Comment: getToday = new Date().  Thanks for your help!